# How to compare this date in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I got some date from sql server like this: '2/23/2012' as HireDate. 
Now when I was trying to filter records like this:
select * from employees where HireDate between '1/1/2012' and date()
It always returns empty. It seems it has problem on converting '2/23/2012' to a Date.

I tried something like these and won't work either!
select strftime('%m/%d/%Y', HireDate) from employees
select strftime('%m/%d/%Y', '2/23/2012')

Very confused. How exactly to compare those two dates?

Thanks.

Comment: try '01/01/2012' maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from employees where HireDate between '01-01-2012 00:00:00' and date('now')
```

This should return employeed hired since first of Jan 2012